# Java GUI Programming close the current Frame

Tags: java, jframe

guys I am new to java programming now I have to deal with GUI programming. I have this simple program for admin to create player for now. I have a view class to show the menus, so when user click on create player the interface will be shown.

then within that menu I have a actionListener which goes to another method and show the pop up menu which then show player created successfully. Now the problem is how can I re show the main menu, and not the create player menu.

There will be a few functions for the admin to deal with but now I just have to finish the first function and the rest will be similar. When clicking on the main menu(create player button) it will go to another function(JFrame) to ask for input, again go to another function to getText from the textfield and save it to file

my codes for tpublic void show() {

```
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Admin");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    mainPanel = new JPanel();
    mainPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,300));
    panel1 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(6,1));


    text = new JLabel("Admin Main Menu");
    text.setFont(new Font("Lucida",Font.PLAIN,24));
    //set panel layout (rows,cols,hgap,vgap)
    panel1.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1,10,10));

    button1 = new JButton("Create a player");
    button2 = new JButton("Delete a player");
    button3 = new JButton("Top up Player's Chips");
    button4 = new JButton("Reset Player's password");
    button5 = new JButton("Change admin's password");
    button6 = new JButton("Logout");

    mainPanel.add(text);
    panel1.add(button1);
    panel1.add(button2);
    panel1.add(button3);
    panel1.add(button4);
    panel1.add(button5);
    panel1.add(button6);
    mainPanel.add(panel1);

    frame.add(mainPanel);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);

    button1.addActionListener(new createPlayerListener());
```

button1 will got to create player menu

```
private class createPlayerListener implements ActionListener
{

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) 
    {
        JFrame frame1 = new JFrame("Admin");
        frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        text = new JLabel("Create a Player");
        text.setFont(new Font("Lucida",Font.PLAIN,24));

        mainPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3,1));
        mainPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,400));
        panel1 = new JPanel();
        //panel1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,200));
        panel1.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,2,10,10));
        name = new JLabel("Enter new player name:");
        nameTextfield = new JTextField();
        pw = new JLabel("Enter new player password:");
        pwTextfield = new JTextField();
        chip = new JLabel("Enter new player chips:");
        chipTextfield = new JTextField();
        button1 = new JButton("Create Player");

        mainPanel.add(text);
        panel1.add(name);
        panel1.add(nameTextfield);
        panel1.add(pw);
        panel1.add(pwTextfield);
        panel1.add(chip);
        panel1.add(chipTextfield);
        mainPanel.add(panel1);
        mainPanel.add(button1);

        frame1.add(mainPanel);
        frame1.pack();
        frame1.setVisible(true);

        button1.addActionListener(new playerListener());

    }
}


private class playerListener implements ActionListener
{

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) 
    {
        String name = nameTextfield.getText();
        String pw = pwTextfield.getText();
        String chip = chipTextfield.getText();
        int chips = Integer.parseInt(chip);
        //System.out.println(text);
        controller.createPlayer(name, pw, chips);

        //pop up window player created
        JFrame frame2 = new JFrame();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame2, "Player Created Successfully!");




    }
}
```

Comment: or can I within the same createPlayerListener able to getText so that I can save it to the file? so then I do not have to call playerListener

Comment: one main issue that I can see quick, is you are instantiating mainPanel twice, in the main code and in the actionPerformed method, the second one is going to override the first one and once the frame1 is disposed, it is not longer valid.

Answer (score 1):

Two issues with your code, creating mainPanel twice, you can do so if you define it locally not globally, otherwise change the names to mainPanel1 and mainPanel2, the second issue is you are calling frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); which closes the application once you close frame1.  I tried this code and it works, see the changes I made to it,

```
JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
mainPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,300));
JPanel panel1 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(6,1));


JLabel text = new JLabel("Admin Main Menu");
text.setFont(new Font("Lucida",Font.PLAIN,24));
//set panel layout (rows,cols,hgap,vgap)
panel1.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1,10,10));

JButton button1 = new JButton("Create a player");
JButton button2 = new JButton("Delete a player");
JButton button3 = new JButton("Top up Player's Chips");
JButton button4 = new JButton("Reset Player's password");
JButton button5 = new JButton("Change admin's password");
JButton button6 = new JButton("Logout");

mainPanel.add(text);
panel1.add(button1);
panel1.add(button2);
panel1.add(button3);
panel1.add(button4);
panel1.add(button5);
panel1.add(button6);
mainPanel.add(panel1);

add(mainPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

button1.addActionListener(new createPlayerListener());
```

Here is your createPlayerListner modified, the playerListner stays the same,

```
private class createPlayerListener implements ActionListener
   {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) 
    {
        JFrame frame1 = new JFrame("Admin");
        JLabel text = new JLabel("Create a Player");
        text.setFont(new Font("Lucida",Font.PLAIN,24));

        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3,1));
        mainPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,400));
        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
        //panel1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,200));
        panel1.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,2,10,10));
        JLabel name = new JLabel("Enter new player name:");
        nameTextfield = new JTextField();
        JLabel pw = new JLabel("Enter new player password:");
        pwTextfield = new JTextField();
        JLabel chip = new JLabel("Enter new player chips:");
        chipTextfield = new JTextField();
        JButton button1 = new JButton("Create Player");

        mainPanel.add(text);
        panel1.add(name);
        panel1.add(nameTextfield);
        panel1.add(pw);
        panel1.add(pwTextfield);
        panel1.add(chip);
        panel1.add(chipTextfield);
        mainPanel.add(panel1);
        mainPanel.add(button1);

        frame1.add(mainPanel);
        frame1.pack();
        frame1.setVisible(true);

        button1.addActionListener(new playerListener());

    }
  }
```